# How to open a .webarchive file in Windows?

Tags: windows, file-types

How to open a .webarchive file in Windows? It seems to be created on Mac. Everything I read says to open it in Safari. Safari doesn't install on my Windows 10 and it's discontinued by Apple. Software I found which say they open it are all malware according to my antivirus software. Word can't open it as some sites claim.

What software and open this file format safely?

Comment: It seems you aren't supposed to open with word. Instead you should use Save As -> WebPage to save it as a valid html file. Just out of curiosity, does 7-zip open it as an archive file?

Comment: Save what in what app? Don't you have to open a file to be able to save it later? 7-zip can't open it

Comment: I meant  Save As option in Word menu. It doesn't have to display as a valid file.

Comment: It didn't work. Garbled text

Comment: Install Safari in Windows...http://www.techspot.com/downloads/4184-safari-for-windows.html

Comment: @Moab I did say it doesn't install and I don't install software from sites I don't trust or know

Comment: Apple no longer has the download for Safari for Windows, so you have to get it from other sources.

Comment: When I said "Safari doesn't install on my Windows 10", I meant I get an error when I install it. I have several versions of the installer from the time it was available years ago. It's discontinued by Apple means there's no newer version which might work on Windows 10 or one that supports .webarchive. I don't know how old this format is. Also maybe Safari Mac can open it but not Safari Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I was actually able to do this on Windows 10.

Install Safari from here: http://www.techspot.com/downloads/4184-safari-for-windows.html (Click "direct download) and then right click the .webarchive file you're trying to open, point to "open with" and choose Safari. It'll open it, along with a print window.

I'd recommend selecting "Microsoft print to PDF" as the printer and saving it as PDF, but if you cancel the print dialog box it'll open in Safari just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have notebook++ for editing html, and was able to get at least the text out of the web archive file like this:
1) save file to computer
2) open file with notebook++
3) save as html
4) open in chrome.

I still had some weird gobbledy gook, but the text was legible, which was all I needed. Thanks to the comment above for making me think of saving as html! (Also notebook++ is free, so that's nice).

Answer (score 1):

## So you want to open a `.webarchive` file in Windows.

### Here are your options:

1. Go back to the original Mac and do a `save as`. If that's an option, then it's the best one.
2. Use an online conversion service (search for "`convert .webarchive to pdf`").

   ***Warning:** they may or may not be keeping a copy of your file.*
3. Install Safari for Windows and use it to open the file.

For me, option 3 was best choice. *Unfortunately,* Apple no longer makes Safari for Windows. ***Fortunately,*** the latest version (5.1.7) seems to still work. *Unfortunately,* Apple no longer provides an easy way to download it. Don't worry, I've got you covered...

### Safe Safari 5.1.7 Download Link:

As of 13 April 2020, you can still download Safari 5.1.7 for Windows directly from Apple using this link: http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe

Since the download is directly from apple.com, you know that it's safe to install.

In case this file is eventually removed, I have saved it directly to web.archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20210413145735/http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe

***WARNING:** This is an old version and is riddled with security flaws. Do not use this to browse the internet.*

### How to open the file:

1. Load Safari.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open the file dialog box and find your file.
3. `Save As` only allows you to save in `.webarchive` format, so if you want to save the file, you must "print" to PDF. So press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to show the print dialog and choose "PDF" as your printer. It will save the file to your disk.

**I can confirm that this all works as of 13 April 2020.**

Answer (score 1):

update 2023-Jan-05

You can use this open source project to unpack `.webarchive`, it has Windows version work with Windows 7 and higher.
It also runs in Linux and macOS.

After unpack, you will get html file and the resource files(like: css, js) in the same place with the original webarchive file.

Project name: pywebarchive, you can get it in [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pywebarchive/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/bmjcode/pywebarchive).

Answer (score 0):

The above conversion to html can work but I had to follow extra steps. The current version of word could not recognise the first lines of text in the webarchive file so embedded the html coding inside lines of garbage. Having opened in word, saved as web page (including selecting html file option in save as pop up box), I opened in a web browser. This showed the html code within the garbage so I copied the html code from where it started !DOCTYPE html in < shaped brackets until /html (again in < shaped brackets) and then pasted in notepad. Then Save as the notepad file as filename.htm and open in any web browser. It can now been viewed and printed as a pdf.