# How to open a (maybe) corrupted webarchive on Windows

Tags: windows-7, macos, webarchive

First of all, is the first time I handle a WARC file...
I have a webarchive file which seems to be corrupted (in some way), I have installed Safari on Windows and I get this (the same thing happen on a Mac):

[image]

I try to open if with 7-zip but it say that is not a valid archive.
I try [this](https://gist.github.com/ktym/4771858) Ruby script but it give me an error too...

What I need is to find a way to extract the files from the archive...any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a .webarchive file in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/1036991/how-to-open-a-webarchive-file-in-windows)

Comment: The problem is not I unable to open it on Windows, but the fact that, when I open it (both on Windows or on Mac), it seems to be corrupted...

Answer (score 0):

> I was actually able to do this on Windows 10.
>
> Install Safari from here: http://www.techspot.com/downloads/4184-safari-for-windows.html (Click "direct download) and then right click the .webarchive file you're trying to open, point to "open with" and choose Safari. It'll open it, along with a print window.
>
> I'd recommend selecting "Microsoft print to PDF" as the printer and saving it as PDF, but if you cancel the print dialog box it'll open in Safari just fine.

Credit: [Pedroelbee](https://superuser.com/users/597108/pedroelbee)

Comment: **Use quote blocks.** Instead of copying verbatim an existing answer, please flag the question as a duplicate of the question with the answer your copying.

Comment: I went ahead and solved your improperly cited answer.  Please take the time to flag duplicates instead of just copying verbatim another answer

Comment: Not really a dupe, but OP says he did it with safari. " have a webarchive file which seems to be corrupted (in some way), I have installed Safari on Windows and I get this (the same thing happen on a Mac):"